# How to automate function according to Array list size

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, formatting

I'm sorry this question header is not 100% correct. Because of that, I'll explain my scenario here.
I created a function to merge 4 data sets into one return format. Because that's the format front-end side needed. So this is working fine now.

```
public ReturnFormat makeThribleLineChart(List<NameCountModel> totalCount, List<NameCountModel>,p1Count, List<NameCountModel> p2Count, List<NameCountModel> average) {

        ReturnFormat returnFormat = new ReturnFormat(null,null);

            try {

                String[] totalData = new String[totalCount.size()];
                String[] p1Data = new String[p1Count.size()];
                String[] p2Data = new String[p2Count.size()];
                String[] averageData = new String[p2Count.size()];
                String[] lableList = new String[totalCount.size()];

                for (int x = 0; x < totalCount.size(); x++) {
                    totalData[x] = totalCount.get(x).getCount();
                    p1Data[x] = p1Count.get(x).getCount();
                    p2Data[x] = p2Count.get(x).getCount();
                    averageData[x] = average.get(x).getCount();
                    lableList[x] = totalCount.get(x).getName();
                }

                FormatHelper<String[]> totalFormatHelper= new FormatHelper<String[]>();
                totalFormatHelper.setData(totalData);
                totalFormatHelper.setType("line");
                totalFormatHelper.setLabel("Uudet");
                totalFormatHelper.setyAxisID("y-axis-1");

                FormatHelper<String[]> p1FormatHelper= new FormatHelper<String[]>();
                p1FormatHelper.setData(p1Data);
                p1FormatHelper.setType("line");
                p1FormatHelper.setLabel("P1 päivystykseen heti");

                FormatHelper<String[]> p2FormatHelper= new FormatHelper<String[]>();
                p2FormatHelper.setData(p2Data);
                p2FormatHelper.setType("line");
                p2FormatHelper.setLabel("P2 päivystykseen muttei yöllä");

                FormatHelper<String[]> averageFormatHelper= new FormatHelper<String[]>();
                averageFormatHelper.setData(averageData);
                averageFormatHelper.setType("line");
                averageFormatHelper.setLabel("Jonotusaika keskiarvo");
                averageFormatHelper.setyAxisID("y-axis-2");

                List<FormatHelper<String[]>> formatHelpObj = new ArrayList<FormatHelper<String[]>>();
                formatHelpObj.add(totalFormatHelper);
                formatHelpObj.add(p1FormatHelper);
                formatHelpObj.add(p2FormatHelper);
                formatHelpObj.add(averageFormatHelper);

                returnFormat.setData(formatHelpObj);
                returnFormat.setLabels(lableList);
                returnFormat.setMessage(Messages.Success);
                returnFormat.setStatus(ReturnFormat.Status.SUCCESS);


            } catch (Exception e) {

                returnFormat.setData(null);
                returnFormat.setMessage(Messages.InternalServerError);
                returnFormat.setStatus(ReturnFormat.Status.ERROR);

            }
            return returnFormat;

    }
```

so, as you can see here, all the formatting is hardcoded. So my question is how to automate this code for list count. Let's assume next time I have to create chart formatting for five datasets. So I have to create another function to it. That's the thing I want to reduce. So I hope you can understand my question.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like each of your datasets has several properties - the data itself, a label and a type - is that correct? If you need to generalise that, I suggest consider using the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: No, All the datasets have the same properties. Data sets contain only two properties. "Name" and "Count" . That means names are the labels and counts are the data. In the upper code, I passed 4 data sets to the param list. I'm planning to pass those data sets as a single list. Then I hoping to loop that list and create a separate string array for each dataset. But my problem is, then I cannot access those variables, because they are in the loop scope. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to solve the more general problem of composing a result object (in this case `ReturnFormat`) based on dynamic information. In addition, there's some metadata being setup along with each dataset - the type, label, etc. In the example that you've posted, you've hardcoded the relationship between a dataset and this metadata, but you'd need some way to establish this relationship for data dynamically if you have a variable number of parameters here.

Therefore, you have a couple of options:

- Make `makeThribleLineChart` a [varargs method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) to accept a variable number of parameters representing your data. Now you have the problem of associating metadata with your parameters - best option is probably to wrap the data and metadata together in some new object that is provided as each param of `makeThribleLineChart`.
  So you'll end up with a signature that looks a bit like `ReturnFormat makeThribleLineChart(DataMetadataWrapper... allDatasets)`, where `DataMetadataWrapper` contains everything required to build one `FormatHelper` instance.
- Use a builder pattern, similar to the [collection builders in guava](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.Builder.html), for example something like so:

```java
class ThribbleLineChartBuilder {
    List<FormatHelper<String[]>> formatHelpObj = new ArrayList<>();

    ThribbleLineChartBuilder addDataSet(String describeType, String label, String yAxisId, List<NameCountModel> data) {
        String[] dataArray = ... ; // build your array of data

        FormatHelper<String[]> formatHelper = new FormatHelper<String[]>();
        formatHelper.setData(dataArray);
        formatHelper.setType(describeType);
        ... // set any other parameters that the FormatHelper requires here

        formatHelpObj.add(formatHelper);

        return this;
    }

    ReturnFormat build() {
        ReturnFormat returnFormat = new ReturnFormat(null, null);
        returnFormat.setData(this.formatHelpObj);
        ... // setup any other fields you need in ReturnFormat

        return returnFormat;
    }
}

// usage:
new ThribbleLineChartBuilder()
 .addDataSet("line", "Uudet", "y-axis-1", totalCount)
 .addDataSet("line", "P1 päivystykseen heti", null, p1Count)
 ... // setup your other data sources
 .build()
```

Comment: Thank you, This was helped a lot.